# loop through field in a matlab struct array

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, matlab-struct

I have a MatLab struct array as follow:

'country.source.scenario.category.entity= year'

I would like to loop over the existing 'country.source.scenario' combinations and produce cell or matrix containing the fields: category, entity and year.
Anyone as an idea about how to do that? Thanks

Comment: please provide a **short** example of what your input looks like and what is your expected output

Comment: @Shai - My input is a tree if data going from "countries" to "sources" to "scenarios" to "categories" to "entities" ending with "years" contained in a <x*x double>. Basically I have all kind of combinations (e.g. USA.CRF.HISTORY.CAT0.CH4= 2000 2001 2002). From that i would like to lock the existing COUNTRY.SOURCE.SCENARIO combination (such as USA.CRF.HISTORY) and build tables (or whatever other outputs) containing CATEGORY and ENTITY as X and Y and filled with the corresponding years.

Comment: press "edit" above and edit details into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fieldnames to get the fields at each level, and isstruct at each sublevel to see if you need to keep drilling, e.g.

```
fields = fieldnames(str);
for field = fields'
    sub = str.(field{1});
    if isstruct(sub)
        %loop through fieldnames
    end
end
```

You can put it in a recursive function whereby inside the if you again call the function. I did not do it like that because it was not clear to me what you wanted as a result, it seemed like you only wanted the tags and not the values at the end.

Comment: @A Hernandez Thank you for your input! I was just doing that way:        for fieldidx=1:length(fields)
         fieldname=fields{fieldidx};
         if isstruct(struct.(fieldname))
but at some point I have any idea about how to organize the loop.

At the end I would like to have an output (table) listing for the CATEGORIES as an header row, and ENTITIES as an header line and filled with the YEAR of each CATEGORIES.ENTITIES combinations!